# Getting an error Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

First off I would like to mention that I have used the search option and looked at multiple different posts as to why I have this problem yet it is still occurring.

In my PHPInfo() I have mySQL installed. In my PHP.ini I have it in the correct directory as per my PHPInfo and I also removed the semicolon in front of extension=php_mysql.so.

I also have the extensions pointing to my extension folder with all the various modules. After all this I still have this error.

Are there any other ways I can go about attempting to fix this issue?

Comment: Is the service running?

Comment: your PHP version is?

Comment: @PatrickBard what command shall I type to ensure I am looking at the right thing and know if its running or not.

Comment: @sectus I have done this every time I modified the Php.ini

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer PHP Version 5.5.21

Comment: @Mookie [Here](http://goo.gl/GIDbbn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Contact to your server administrator** or do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Will install package containing mysqli and mysql, so afterwards all you need to do is restart apache and it should work.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Sorry about this Adrian! I forgot to mention that I am connecting via ssh to my schools host cluster. Thus I can't use sudo since i don't know the root password. Is there another way to do this but for my specific account on the cluster?

Comment: @Mookie yes, Contact to your server administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have missing the mysqli extension. You need to installed first sqli extension than you can use its functions..

Please have a look on the link to configured of all version of mysqli.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php